# GreenPlum SQL statement migration into HiveSQL

Tags: postgresql, hive, hiveql, greenplum

We are migrating Greenplum to HiveSQL and please help me as below statement needs to convert. kindly help us.

```
GREENPLUM - ||trim(to_char(sum(revenue),'9,999,999,999'))
```

hive will not supported `to_char` so that equal property we have to put in hive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cast(col as STRING)` to convert to char and use `format_number(146452664,0)` to display as comma separated value in hive.
here you sql should look like -

```
SUBSTR(cast( format_number(sum(revenue)),0) as string),1,13)
```

I am using a substring in the end to get only 10 integers.

Comment: lpad(hex_to_int(lac),5,'0')|| --how do convert this, especially hex_to_int

Comment: You can use `conv(string, int_from_base, int_to_base)`. This converts a string from one base to another. Like `conv('hexval',16,10)` will return integer. You can see some example in google as well.

Comment: but if we add lpad with conv, it is throwing error. is it required or else we have to use only conv only. please help me

Comment: ('41405'||lpad(Conv(lac,5,0))||lpad(Conv(ci,5,0)) --this i tried but not working

Comment: SUBSTR(cast( format_number(sum(revenue)),0) as string),1,13) --this function not working and throwing EOF error

Comment: can you pls post complete SQL here?

Comment: trim(to_char(sum(revenue),'9,999,999,999')) -- i find solution but not sure  trim(regexp_replace(sum(revenue), '(?!^)(\\d\\d\\d(?=(\\d\\d\\d)*\\b))', ',$1'))