# GreenPlum UDF function convert to Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql, greenplum

We have to migrate Greenplum to Hive, please help me below statement.

```
1. ('41405'||lpad(hex_to_int(lac),5,'0')||lpad(hex_to_int(ci),5,'0'))
2. lpad(hex_to_int(lac),5,'0')
```

Comment: you can refer to comment section to your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69280234/greenplum-sql-statement-migration-into-hivesql/69281420?noredirect=1#comment122454586_69281420

Answer (score 0):

To convert hex to int, use `conv(str, 16, 10)` function.
In older versions of Hive use [concat()](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+udf#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) for concatenation.
[lpad](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+udf#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) function exists in Hive

Comment: ('41405'||lpad(Conv(lac,5,0))||lpad(Conv(ci,5,0)) - this is i tried but not working